# WPF InstallShield LE - Copying files to output subdirectory

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, installshield, installshield-le

In my solution, I have created a Folder called Elements with a HTML page (used for some functions in my WPF C# application) called MyJS.html. In the properties, I have it as:

Build action = Content
Copy to output Directory = Copy always

How can I have this file copied over to the output directory and have it in the correct subfolder Elements as at the minute it does not install that file at all (not even creating the folder Elements) and thus is missing a critical element of my app for it's good functioning.